# binary output for python def function

Tags: function, python-3.x, binary

New:

I am now working on a calculator for the terminal. I'm having the same error as before. but this time its telling me this: `<function div at 0x7faf88c9e488>`

code is at : https://github.com/mishiki1002/Solo-Calculater/blob/master/Solo-Main.py

Solved:

I have been programming in python for Year and a half. I have played around with the def function and variables. My current programming project is a RPG Fantasy type game. I am currently still at the begging and i am wondering what kind of output this is and why i am getting it. I believe it is some kind of binary bit.

```
<function showInstructions at 0x7fa8933162f0>
```

when i compile my code through my terminal using python main.py that is what i get. This is my full source code for the game. Please leave any comments and or suggestions for my programming. Also please tell me if my code is sloppy. I try and document all i can so its easier for me and programmers around me to read it.

Sincerely Josh

```
   !/usr/bin/python3

#We will import this so that we have a random in counter chance for the game.
#this will all so prove use full when we have attacks sequences and Loot drops
from random import randint

class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        #This is the name that you have made for your character
        self.name = ' '
        #Amount of health for you character
        self.health = 100
        #Max amount of health for your character
        self.health_max = 9999
    #Damage class to define the attack methods needed to Battle?
    def do_damage(self, enemy):
        #Defining a varible called damage. Stating that the minimum damage can be 0. And No less than that, for either
        damage = min(
            # Stating that the minimum damage can be 0. And No less than that, for either character
            max(radint(0, self.health)) - randint(0, enemy.health), 0), (enemy.health)
        #Actual Damage System
        enemy.health = enemy.health - damage
        #Printing the product to the user/gamer
        if damamge ==0: "%s evades %s's attack." % (enemy.name , self.name)
        #If you land a hit
        else: print("%s hurts %s!" % (self.name, enemy.name))
        #printing your enemys health so you know how much left un-till 0
        return enemy.health <= 0

class Enemy(Character):
    def __init__(self, player):
        #Since we declared that the enemy is a character it takes a characters paramaters
        Character.__init__(self)
        #It needs a name Like a Goblin
        self.name = 'a Goblin'
        #And it needs health
        self.health = randint(1, 15 + player.health)

class Player(Character):
    #Now we are delcaring a Side characters role
    def __init__(self, player):
        Character.__init__(self)
        #when you check out the menu to see how your characters are doing you will see a meesage saying Normal and
        #the amount of health they have
        self.state = 'Normal'
        #Now we set their health
        self.health = 100
        #Max Health
        self.health_max = 9999
    #Start Menu will be here
def showInstructions():
    print("Sound_Soul")
    print("----------")
    print("Commmands:")
    print(" 'go [direction]'")
    print("The Cardinal Directions:")
    print(" north")
    print(" east")
    print(" south")
    print(" west")

print (showInstructions)
```

Comment: In addition to my answer below: I used to put comments on almost every line of code too but actually it makes code harder to read. Ideally code should be clear as written. I found that leaving a lot of my comments out is actually making my code easier to read. Comments are great for places where things are complex, confusing and otherwise not obvious. But something like Class enemy, name goblin is pretty clear without an additional comment.

Comment: Thank you Igor for the help.

Comment: Glad to help. See the edit on my answer as well.

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted and ask a new question. There is no need to track two separate questions in one.

Comment: It is the same mistake as before on line 42    ``print (add)`` should be    ``print (add())``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that because you are using only function name `showInstructions` instead of a call to the function like so `showInstructions()`.

Edit:

One more thing: you don't need to also use print when calling your function as you already have print statements within your function. This causes "None" to be printed below your intended text because the function indeed return `None` by default.